# Как изменить шрифт и размер текста SwipeSelector material design

Tags: java, android

```
 <com.roughike.swipeselector.SwipeSelector
        android:id="@+id/swipeSelector1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        app:swipe_descriptionGravity="center"

        />
```

Как изменить шрифт и размер текста `SwipeSelector`?
Ссылка на библиотеку: https://github.com/roughike/SwipeSelector

Comment: ссылку дайте хотя бы на SwipeSelector

Comment: На главной странице библиотеки это все описано

Comment: я посмотрел не смог разобраться може тпояснее скажите

Comment: нет, извините, я копипастить от туда не буду. Там есть раздел `Customization`, где все описано. Прочитайте его.

Comment: там определен четкий способ, как все сделать. Это сторонняя библиотека. Вы можете попросить автора библиотеки добавить еще один способ, если этот вас не устраивает. Но вы в вопросе написали, что хотите знать, как это сделать. А я прокомментировал, что на странице библиотеки есть описание, как это сделать. Откуда же я могу знать, что вам почему-то этот способ не подходит? И напишите хотя бы, почему он вам не подходит, раз уж на то пошло